# How to make ActiveRecord query unique by a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `Company` model that has many `Disclosures`. The `Disclosure` has columns named `title`, `pdf` and `pdf_sha256`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disclosures
end

class Disclosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I want to make it unique by `pdf_sha256` and if `pdf_sha256` is `nil` that should be treated as unique.

If it is an `Array`, I'll write like this.

```
companies_with_sha256 = company.disclosures.where.not(pdf_sha256: nil).group_by(&:pdf_sha256).map do |key,values|
  values.max_by{|v| v.title.length}
end
companies_without_sha256 = company.disclosures.where(pdf_sha256: nil)
companies = companies_with_sha256 + companeis_without_sha256
```

How can I get the same result by using ActiveRecord query?

Comment: Please follow this link answered by me.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577181/7329402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it in one query by first getting a different `id` for each different `pdf_sha256` as a subquery, then in the query getting the elements within that set of ids by passing the subquery as follows:

```
def unique_disclosures_by_pdf_sha256(company)
  subquery = company.disclosures.select('MIN(id) as id').group(:pdf_sha256)
  company.disclosures.where(id: subquery)
    .or(company.disclosures.where(pdf_sha256: nil))
end
```

The great thing about this is that ActiveRecord is lazy loaded, so the first `subquery` will not be run and will be merged to the second main query to create a single query in the database. It will then retrieve all the `disclosures` unique by `pdf_sha256` plus all the ones that have `pdf_sha256` set to `nil`.

In case you are curious, given a company, the resulting query will be something like:

```
SELECT  "disclosures".* FROM "disclosures" 
WHERE (
  "disclosures"."company_id" = $1 AND "disclosures"."id" IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM "disclosures" WHERE "disclosures"."company_id" = $2 GROUP BY "disclosures"."pdf_sha256"
  ) 
  OR "disclosures"."company_id" = $3 AND "disclosures"."pdf_sha256" IS NULL
)
```

The great thing about this solution is that the returned value is an ActiveRecord query, so it won't be loaded until you actually need. You can also use it to keep chaining queries. Example, you can select only the `id` instead of the whole model and limit the number of results returned by the database:

```
unique_disclosures_by_pdf_sha256(company).select(:id).limit(10).each { |d| puts d }
```

Comment: What can I do if I can't do `MAX(id)` because I have UUID valued ID-s. I tried `select('MAX(created_at) as created_at').group(:feed_type)`, but I still need ID-s to make next queries and search records by ID-s.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using uniq method

```
 Company.first.disclosures.to_a.uniq(&:pdf_sha256)
```

This will return you the disclosures records uniq by cloumn "pdf_sha256"

Hope this helps you! Cheers

Comment: `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#uniq` is just a alias of `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#distinct`. Therefore the method doesn't work in this case. I think you mixed up with `Array#uniq`. Your code works with `to_a` method like `company.disclosures.to_a.uniq(&:pdf_sha256)`.

Comment: Thanks @ironsand. I have edited my answer. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Rails 5 you could chain a .or command to merge both your queries.

```
pdf_sha256_unique_disclosures = company.disclosures.where(pdf_sha256: nil).or(company.disclosures.where.not(pdf_sha256: nil))
```

Then you can proceed with your group_by logic.

However, in the example above i'm not exactly sure what is the objective but I am curious to better understand how you would use the resulting `companies` variable.

If you wanted to have a hash of unique pdf_sha256 keys including nil, and its resultant unique disclosure document you could try the following:

```
sorted_disclosures = company.disclosures.group_by(&:pdf_sha256).each_with_object({}) do |entries, hash|
  hash[entries[0]] = entries[1].max_by{|v| v.title.length}
end
```

This should give you a resultant hash like structure similar to the group_by where your keys are all your unique pdf_sha256 and the value would be the longest named disclosure that match that pdf_sha256.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
ids = Disclosure.select(:id, :pdf_sha256).distinct.map(&:id)
Disclosure.find(ids)
```

The id sill be distinct either way since it's the primary key, so all you have to do is map the ids and find the Disclosures by id.

Comment: I want to get all columns of `disclosure` models filter by uniqueness of the `pdf_sha256`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a relation with distinct `pdf_sha256`, where you require no explicit conditions, you can use [group](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) for that -

```
scope :unique_pdf_sha256, -> { where.not(pdf_sha256: nil).group(:pdf_sha256) }
scope :nil_pdf_sha256,    -> { where(pdf_sha256: nil) }
```

You could have used `or`, but the relation passed to it must be structurally compatible. So even if you get same type of relations in these two scopes, you cannot use it with `or`.

**Edit**: To make it structurally compatible with each other you can see @AlexSantos 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754201/8774386)

Answer (score -1):

```
Model.select(:rating)
```

Result of this is an array of Model objects. Not plain ratings. And from uniq's point of view, they are completely different. You can use this:

```
Model.select(:rating).map(&:rating).uniq
```

or this (most efficient)

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)

Model.distinct.pluck(:rating)
```

Update

Apparently, as of rails 5.0.0.1, it works only on "top level" queries, like above. Doesn't work on collection proxies ("has_many" relations, for example).

```
Address.distinct.pluck(:city) # => ['Moscow']
user.addresses.distinct.pluck(:city) # => ['Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Moscow']
```

In this case, deduplicate after the query

```
user.addresses.pluck(:city).uniq # => ['Moscow']
```

Comment: In your example I want to get all columns of `addresses`, not only the `city` column.